# Django Rest Framework: User Update

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I know this has been discussed and it's basic but I can't find what is wrong with it. I've pulled up my old projects (which works!) and corresponded to what I did. It never reaches to update in serializer, and I'm at lost why. 
I dont know what else I'm missing.

**Error**:

> {"last_name":["This field may not be null."],"pass…
>   null."],"email":["This field may not be null."]}, status: 400

frontend `patch('api/getprofile')`

django/DRF **serializer**:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField()
    last_name = serializers.CharField()
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'})

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            username=validated_data.get('username'),
            email=validated_data.get('email'),
            password=validated_data.get('password')
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data.get('password'))
        user.save()
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        #print instance <-- if never gets here... is update not update
        for key, value in validated_data.items():
            if value:
                print value
                setattr(instance, key, value)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

**views.py**

```
class UserRetrieveUpdateAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)
        instance = serializer.instance
        return Response(UserSerializer(instance=instance).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule UPDATE the data.

Answer (score 1):

The only implementation that you may need to provide for your `APIView` is the `get_object` method.

From the source for [`mixins.UpdateMixins`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.9.0/rest_framework/mixins.py#L65), `update` (for HTTP PUT requests) and `partial_update` are implemented as you have it.

The override for the `mixins.UpdateMixins.update` you provide allows partial updates on `HTTP PUT` requests and misses passing the model instance to the serializer for the update. *i.e.*

```
serializer = UserSerializer(self.get_object(), data=request.data, partial=True)
```

I however suggest to not perform the override for `mixins.UpdateMixins.update` in the current manner. 

Use the standard handling of the HTTP requests implemented in `mixins.UpdateMixins` and only provide your implementation for `.get_object()`.

You do this already with `UserRetrieveUpdateAPIView.get_object()`.